# How do I copy the HTML and user input, then send it to the server in an HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to copy the HTML along with the user's input, but I haven't had any luck. This is my code where I try to clone the form, then http it to the php file where it would be saved. I know it won't work because I need to append it.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit_form()
{ 
    var xmlHttp = null;
    var formData = new FormData();
    var form = document.getElementById('form_div');
    var cln = form.cloneNode(true);
    var saveForm = '<html><body>' + cln + '</body></html>';
    formData.append("saveform", saveForm);
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xmlHttp.open('POST', 'http.php?nocache='+crt_date, true);

    xmlHttp.send(formData);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {         
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200)
            {
                var responsetext = xmlHttp.responseText;
                alert("Your request was sent, " + responsetext);
            }
            else
            {
                var err_str = "There was a problem retrieving the data +\n";
                err_str += "statusText = " + xmlHttp.statusText + "\n";
                err_str += "status = " + xmlHttp.status;
            }

        }
    } 
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <DIV id = "form_div">
            <FORM id = "form">
                <INPUT type = "text" value = "" id = "example" name = "example">
                <INPUT type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:submit_form()">
            </FORM>
        </DIV>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Where do you set `copy`?

Comment: You don't need a cache-buster when using POST, they're never cached.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `cln` variable, you never use it? Is that supposed to be `copy`?

Comment: I edited to code to better reflect the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't concatenate a node with a string, you need to use the `innerHTML` property to get the HTML.

But the HTML of an input doesn't include changes to its value. If you want this change to be reflected, you need to copy the `value` property to the `value` attribute.

```
var cln = form.cloneNode(true);
cln.querySelector("#example").setAttribute("value", document.querySelector("#example").value);
var saveForm = '<html><body>' + cln.innerHTML + '</body></html>';
```

Comment: I tried the code, but I get this error. Uncaught TypeError: cln.getElementById is not a function

Comment: In this example, querySelector is not needed because the data should be in the form when it is cloned. So just skip the line, cln.querySelector ....

Comment: @VectorVortec The attribute needs to be set on the `<input>`, not the `<form>`.

Comment: The "not a function" is probably because the routine, "submit_form()", is not defined.

Comment: @VectorVortec If that were the cause it would say `submit_form is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, this is what you are trying to do,

```
var xmlHttp = null;
var formData = new FormData();
var form = document.getElementById('form_div');
var cln = form.cloneNode(true);
var saveForm = '<html><body>' + cln.innerHTML + '</body></html>';
formData.append("saveform", saveForm);
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
console.log(saveForm);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/VectorVortec/7ycbw0tg/7/

It is a question of whether the form is filled at the time of the clone. If it is, then this code works. If not, then the selected answer should be used.